# How to fix weird edges when doing knife project?

Tags: modifiers, knife-tool, project

I am quite new to hard surface modeling but wanted to get into it a little bit. I am doing *something* like a Porsche 911 back and wanted to cut out the bonnet area. Since I thought Knife project would be easier than boolean modif I used that. I also used edge wight and bevel modif to make harder edges. After making the cut it produced those weird shapes, fliping one of the UVs helped near the bottom, but not completely. I know its something to do with the weird face and the fact that its an N-gon, but connecting the corners to something doesn't help at all.
Any and all help will be **super** helpfull.

[image]

here is a link to the .blend file >
 https://drive.google.com/open?id=1aodNFbnb5AjM3tHgwmuXCke7z6NYVbBY
I dont know how else to add it sorry.

there are also rough background images that I have been building off of. I dont need the whole car, just the back of it that is the reason why it cuts off like that.

Comment: I'd suggest looking at some references to see what you are going for https://3dexport.com/items/2005/05/06/1656/228642/porsche_911_gt3_rs_2019_3d_model_c4d_max_obj_fbx_ma_lwo_3ds_3dm_stl_2400703_o.jpg and https://i.pinimg.com/originals/3f/55/60/3f55605e3655f5bd76474ced932aef73.jpg and some tutorials on modeling. In your case you have probably non-concave Ngon which won't provide any good topology flow; since reflections are important here you want to make all quads in this case

Comment: Before using Bevel modifier and this kind of tool, try to keep only quads. Also, you'll probably need to create some additional edge loops to keep your angles sharp. But maybe show some pictures of this car and share your file so that we can work on it.

Comment: @moonboots I wanted to avoid using edge loops as it tends to get really messy after a while, thats why I chose to go with the modifiers. The car is a 1976 911 Turbo. I'm not planing on making it exact, but close to it. I also edited the original Q to add the file.

Comment: @MrZak So in short - You would sudgest that I do not use any other tools than the standart loop-cuts, extrudes, move, roate, to keep the model basic. Because using boolean or knife project it would create weird faces, right?

Comment: Boolean or Knife project indeed can cause ngons or tris within their workflow however it's not a reason to skip using them since you always can correct any ngon later with knife or joining edges to cut faces. In some cases you might also skip converting ngons but not in the mentioned above. Note also that cars' body is not done out of one piece rather than multiple, that's what simplifies the task actually. There are many tutorials on YT on modeling cars especially, I suggest start from there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically. Learn something new every day, even if it's super simple. Conecting Ngon edges to some lines solved the weird bits. I used Knife tool and made every odd shape into little squares.